# Is right to call Microservice a project that is just an adapter?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices

Let's think I have a project that manage games. In this project, I use request X for example.

But I had to create a new project to use request Y. We can think that is to be conformed with some standards of API for games manager. In this new project, I only have mapping being done. The project that uses request Y change the request to X and call the API.
There is no business logic, only mapping logic. So, we can see that new project is a kind of adapter. In this new project I have a different development, deployment and team managing.

My question is: is right to call the new project of microservice? The new one is highly coupled of the core (the one that manage games) and doesn't work without it.

Comment: I'd call it a proxy. I wouldn't even create new stuff but rather rely on something that already exists, like a Nginx container, to do this job

Comment: You absolutely can call the new project a Microservice. All you need for a Microservice is _independent deployability_. "The golden rule: can you make a change to a service and deploy it by itself without changing anything else?"  --Sam Newman, Building Microservices.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thank you @jaco0646